# simple image processing without GIMP

Tags: linux, unix

I am using linux, and I want to do simple image processing.
Given an image (.jpg) I want to cut a small square portion of that and save it as mySmallSqaure.jpg.
Is there a simple way to do this without using GIMP? I only want this kind of process, so I was thinking using GIMP would be heavy considering that I am only cutting small portion.

Any lightweight software to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want a command line tool, you can use the already mentioned ImageMagick, if you want a GUI, you could try xpaint, fspot and a lot of other tools, that will probably do the job. 
BTW, this seems for like a question for superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

gThumb

```
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```